# Get total term frequencies by date query

Tags: solr

I'd like to know the "top 10 terms" from a query (which is just a date range query).  I need "total term frequency" by date...**not** a count of documents and **not** just a count of term frequency across the entire index.  I've looked into the Solr TermsComponent and Lucene's HighFreqTerms, but neither seems to support the operation I want as the result of a query.

My index is pretty simple...every item goes into the 'content' field which also has a 'dateCreated' field (to support the query).  Any thoughts to the technique I could use?

Answer (score 0):

When you query for the date in question, you can iterate through the [`scoreDoc`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ScoreDoc.html)s returned, and [get `TermVector`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVector%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)s for the content field like:

```
Terms terms = myIndexReader.getTermVector(currentScoreDoc.doc, "content");
```

and you can then iterate through [`terms.iterator()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/Terms.html#iterator%28org.apache.lucene.index.TermsEnum%29), and create a collection of counts for each of the terms (acquired from the [`TermsEnum.next()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/BytesRefIterator.html#next%28%29) or [`TermsEnum.term()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermsEnum.html#term%28%29) methods)

Answer (score 0):

[Faceting](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Faceting) provides almost what you're looking for, but will give document frequencies for each term, not the total term frequencies. Make your date range query as a `/select` call, then add parameters:
* `rows=0` since you don't want to see the documents found, just counts
* `facet=true`
* `facet.field=<the field with the required terms>`
* `facet.limit=10` since you want top ten terms

Over a field called `text`, part of the response would look like:

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
  <lst name="facet_queries"/>
  <lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="text">
      <int name="from">3690</int>
      <int name="have">3595</int>
      <int name="it">3495</int>
      <int name="has">3450</int>
      <int name="one">3375</int>
      <int name="who">3221</int>
      <int name="he">3137</int>
      <int name="up">3125</int>
      <int name="all">3112</int>
      <int name="year">3089</int>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <lst name="facet_dates"/>
  <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
```

Warning, this request may be slow!